# Page appears indexed in Google but not findable for any search terms?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, creative-commons

(Note that I am going to use screenshots here because I suspect writing about this will change the behavior over time.)

If you do a Google search for

> uiviewcontroller best practices

either with or without the quotes, you end up with results like this:

[image]

[image]

Note that **none of these pages resolve to the actual Stack Overflow question containing those words in the title**. They resolve to either a) sites that are mirroring our creative commons data *and* correctly pointing back to the source question without nofollow, as properly specified by [our attribution requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/) or b) our own internal links to the question, but not the actual question itself.

The actual page with the title ...

> Custom UIView and UIViewController best practices?

... *does* exist at this URL ...

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300183/custom-uiview-and-uiviewcontroller-best-practices`

... and apparently it is present in Google's index!

[image]

But why does it *not* appear when we search for

> uiviewcontroller best practices

?

We know that

- Google contains this page in its index
- Our search terms match the title of the question
- Stack Overflow has much higher pagerank than the other sites that are [mirroring this question under Creative Commons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/)

I don't get it. What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood I've been noticing that other sites that mirror Stack Overflow content are coming up before Stack Overflow in searches for questions. I'm not sure what's causing it, but it doesn't give me a warm-fuzzy.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't paid your Google bill this month.  I wonder if it's content related...are there any stop words in say one of the ads that displayed when the page was indexed?

Comment: @george it's the above issue, or the page isn't indexed at all.

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in your sitemap, but I can't see, because Stackoverflow blocks sitemap access to non-search-engines.  Could you add the relevant snippet from your sitemap to the question?

Comment: @dan sitemap is irrelevant here; see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox -- but you can assume this WAS in the sitemap of the last 50k active questions at the time it was asked.

Comment: Once (I think it was yesterday) an answer of me was indexed nearly immediately. Just after I've posted my answer (merely after a few seconds), I hit Google to get more insight about the issue. As hard as believable, the very first result was my own answer! So there seems to be two far ends to the situation. What about building a mirror/spam site for SO? Ok, it was a bad joke. The bad thing is, Google is not very verbose on these issues...

Comment: @Jeff There's not enough room in this comment to argue about sitemaps, but in Google's paper "Sitemaps: Above and Beyond the Crawl of Duty", Google describes the sitemap as just a page on your site.  If you want to pass PageRank to pages without directly linking to them in your UI, you use a sitemap.  That's exactly what you want to do on StackOverflow, as I understand it. (Sitemaps also have a huge benefit for refresh crawling, allowing Google to use the lastmod date to avoid unnecessary refresh.)

Comment: @dan "Sitemaps also have a huge benefit for refresh crawling" which is why we limit it to the last 50k updated questions. It also has benefit for speed of indexing. But for deep url discoverability, it does absolutely nothing in our experience.

Answer (score 12):

There's not much you can do about this.  There's a teensy bit you can do to help, but the problem is endemic to Google's index.

- There isn't just one Google "index;" it's sharded. Pages with low PageRank appear in very few shards. Using `site:stackoverflow.com` forces your query onto a shard that has a larger fraction of your URLs indexed.  That explains the contradictory results you see: the search results are coming from different shards.
- PageRank applies to *pages*, not domains.  Yes, really.  Since the StackOverflow home page has high PageRank, the home page can flow PageRank to other question pages, but if your home page doesn't link to this particular Question page, then the Question's effective PageRank is very low.
- <s>You can also flow PageRank via your XML sitemap.  According to [this paper](http://www2009.org/proceedings/pdf/p991.pdf):</s>

  > The root of the domain is assumed to contain an implicit link to the Sitemaps ﬁle. In  addition, the Sitemaps ﬁle is assumed to contain links to all of its URLs, either uniformly weighted or weighted by priority if this ﬁeld is provided. Over this augmented
  >   graph, PageRank can be calculated for every URL in the Sitemaps page.
- StackOverflow doesn't link to every question on the site; it only links to a tiny minority of questions for a very brief period of time.  <s>Furthermore, it's my understanding that you guys even delete links from your sitemap, only linking to the most recent questions.</s>  So many pages on the site receive no benefit from the home page's very high PageRank.

So, you can help this problem a little bit by <s>making sure your XML sitemap is 100% complete (not just the newest questions, but ALL of them) and by</s> making sure that every question page can be reached by a short chain of links starting from the home page.

But even that won't always work; you can't reasonably expect *every* page on your site to have high PageRank.  In those cases, those pages will be crawled, but probably won't appear on a lot of shards, so Google won't always return them.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** Jeff hates sitemaps, so I updated this answer to make it easier for him to read.

Comment: This is another good reason to have a site map thus answering http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox

Comment: I could not disagree more w/r/t Sitemaps; none of the empirical data we have bears this out. If Google can't spider your site, sitemap is worthless. However, Google should be able to spider `questions?page=1` through `questions?page=9999` and until about 2 weeks ago this was *explicitly* suppressed to them in favor of the sitemap (which, uh, didn't work).

Comment: @dan even for sites which fit in the sitemap (eg they have less than 50k questions) we have seen this phenomenon of no weight given to the links. You're giving dangerous and incorrect -- in my experience -- advice w/r/t the sitemap. On top of that, you can clearly see IN THE SCREENSHOTS I POSTED that we link to this question, on multiple pages! Take a closer look... http://i.imgur.com/PfyMz.png

Comment: @adam incorrect; it's another part of the dangerous fallacies surrounding sitemap. The consensus on that question was that sitemaps are good for speed of indexing and refreshing changed content and nothing else.

Comment: @Jeff I didn't say that a sitemap would solve your problem; I said that there's very little you can do, but a sitemap would help.  This problem will always happen, even with perfect site architecture, because of sharding.  But you're arguing that since sitemaps didn't completely fix your problem, sitemaps don't even help, which is more, I think, than you can actually show.

Comment: @Jeff I was assuming Dan was correct. You're right. It appears that no one has, as far as I can tell, experienced increased page rank from site maps and indeed that's all Google claims it will do.

Comment: @Jeff Go ahead and ignore everything I said about sitemaps.  I think that's a mistake, but it's a small mistake; little harm done.  Instead, please update your post with the *chain of links* from your home page to this Question page.  Hint: if it goes through `questions?page=5` and then `?page=10` and then `?page=15`, it's probably not a very short chain; that's a problem for you.

Comment: @dan agreed, and that makes more sense.

Comment: @Dan I suspect you're on to it, if the homepage of the site doesn't link to the page very directly, then you're telling Google that page is not important. If that page *is* important, then get linking to it :)  For sites like this we really need a tool to answer the question: how far away from the homepage is a given page, and what does the site's linkgraph look like.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it makes a difference, but looking at efreedom's page source code I noticed they're using google_ad_section_start and google_ad_section_end markers (http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23168). Could this allow Google to better weigh the actual content of the site?

Also, the actual content seems to be closer to the top of the page, whereas with SO there's a lot of ceremony going on before the actual content (this may not matter either, just a guess).

Answer (score 0):

Very short and super easy answer. Ping the question.

I work in SEO, and this is how I make my tens of dollars a year ;)... things showing up in the big G.

I have spent thousands upon thousands of dollars working on tool that speed all of this up for me.

2 things make you show up before the rest (for exact phrases)

1. Spider Crawls
2. Inbound links

Ping the page, ping the sitemap, and let the mirrors point back to you... There is a phrase we have in the SEO world, it is the Google Dance, you will bounce up and down the results latter while Google finds where to place you "permanently."

**EDIT**

For better clarity, here is a PDF about the different google bots http://www.telezent.com/telezent/Resources/FAMILY-OF-GOOGLE-CRAWLERS.pdf

Comment: what does ping'ing a page mean?

Answer (score 0):

An important SEO consideration is your site's internal linking scheme--internal linking affects both spiderability and the weighting of pages in your site.

One of the guidelines for internal linking is that pages should contain no more than ~100 links--more than 100 starts to look spammy (to a crawler) and dilutes the value of each link to the point where each link isn't very valuable at all, even though you're linking from a high-authority page.

It's interesting to note that the Stack Overflow home page has approximately 700 links in its source code, whereas Efreedom only has about 35. Individual topic pages on SO have 100+ links, while Efreedom only has about 30.

All that being said, the Google Index serving me results seems to be getting things right, with SO on top (at least for the 10 searches I tried).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's any location-specific issue here?

From my desk in central London (the UK version) I just Googled `uiviewcontroller best practices` and the first three results were SO, with a single efreedom link at #4. That's a [google.co.uk](http://google.co.uk) search.

In general, I think I see SO links higher in Google's search results - I actually wasn't aware of eFreedom at all prior to today.

I note that [Alexa's eFreedom entry](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/efreedom.com) has it at #568 for India - perhaps there's some particular bias with Indian-based searches?

Comment: I'd suggest google has updated its index several times since the question was asked almost a month ago.